# javascript: cloneNode causes scripts execution in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ieaddon

I have been using cloneNode API on DOM objects implemented natively by browsers. Behavior looks fine in FF and chrome, but in IE the scripts inside the node to be cloned is also getting executed as a side effect of the cloneNode api.

Is there a way I can get rid from that?

Comment: this issue isn't there in IE10.

Comment: **I'm observing this problem in IE9** but not in lower versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does cloneNode need to be used when appending a documentFragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858129/why-does-clonenode-need-to-be-used-when-appending-a-documentfragment)