# Why does cloneNode need to be used when appending a documentFragment?

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, documentfragment

I've been looking at using documentFragments in a Backbone.js app and was wondering why I see examples where "cloneNode" is used when appending the documentFragment to the parent DOM element.

An example can be seen [here](http://jsperf.com/appendchild-vs-documentfragment-vs-innerhtml/15). If you look down at the DocumentFragment section you'll see this:

```
oFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0, imax = aElms.length; i < imax; i++) {
 oFrag.appendChild(aElms[i]);
}

o.innerHTML = '';
o.appendChild(oFrag.cloneNode(true));
```

Why does "oFrag" get cloned instead of just appending it? Another [blog post](http://backbonefu.com/2012/01/optimizing-the-views-list-creation-with-document-fragment/) doesn't use "cloneNode" (as a comparison).

Comment: +1, very interesting indeed. My only (and quite wild) guess is that `cloneNode` usage gives us better control over `oFrag` scope.

Comment: I don't think this deserves to be forged into a full answer, but anyway... Simply by looking for 'documentFragment cloneNode' I've found [this post](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) of John Resig. ) In this post's topic a bunch of nodes should be inserted into DOM _several_ times, thus cloning documentFragment is indeed a better choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [first link](http://jsperf.com/appendchild-vs-documentfragment-vs-innerhtml/15) refers to the [blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) where the autor uses `document.getElementsByTagName` instead of `document.getElementById`, like in test case. If you want a multiple elements (namely: divs) to be given the same `documentFragment`, you must clone it:

> If child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild moves it from its current position to the new position (i.e. there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).
>
> This also means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, it is first removed, then appended at the new position.

via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

Most likely the author (or someone else) copy-pasted the code without taking this into consideration. Try it yourself - you can use `appendChild` without `cloneNode` and everything works fine.

Another possibility is that someone who created this test case on jsperf didn't get much how preparation code works and was worried that the very first test will empty `aElms` array and it won't work anymore. [In fact](http://jsperf.com/faq#setup-teardown) preparation code is executed before each timed iteration, so there's no need to be worried about its contents.

The last thing may the performance concern. If you really want to test the **real insertion**, you need to clone the node. Otherwise, you'll test tree **reattachment** instead (see MDN link above).

Also please note that [cloning destroys event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode).

Happy fragmentin'! ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you append a documentFragment to an element, and you later clear the appended nodes from that element, your documentFragment will also be empty and cannot be reused anymore! Appending a clone of your documentFragment prevents this and allows multiple reuses of your documentFragment.

I assume the author of the jsperf snippet was testing for such a case.

Example: dropdowns with a parent-child relationship. Lets say you have a dropdown where you select a continent, and a second dropdown that lists all the countries in that continent. If you want to cache the created documentFragments with the option nodes after creation, using cloneNode is necessary. Imagine someone selects europe, then africa, then europe again: you can either recreate the entire documentfragment, of cache it.

I created a jsperf snippet to illustrate the performance difference of recreating the documentFragments vs caching and cloning the fragments:

http://jsperf.com/documentfragment-cache-vs-recreate

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure, but in the context of the link you provided (performance testing) the `oFrag.cloneNode(true)` might be a safeguard against reusing the elements already added in DOM in previous runs of the loop, which would result in way faster execution of the test.

I see no reason to use it in normal use cases of documentFragments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessary. I guess it only was used to detach the `aElms` from being statically referenced, where they would've need to be removed from their former parents when calling `appendChild`. It's only for performance in this test.

However, the following code (more similar to the `appendChild` test) would make more sense to me:

```
var oFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0, imax = aElms.length; i < imax; i++)
    oFrag.appendChild(aElms[i].cloneNode(true));
// using it here:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
o.appendChild(oFrag);
```

Though it might be slower than calling it only once on the whole fragment, where the node tree is recursed with native code.

Also check out http://jsperf.com/cloning-fragments :-)